# Using HTML components inside a jsf page cause HTML components coordinates are not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, dom

Hi i am put a HTML component and another HTML component alignment is very good inside a html page,for example:put a div component and an input component alignment inside a html page.

[image]

But, when I put the code after transplantation into the JSF page,They are not accurate alignment by the following code:

```
/**
*get the first component coordinates
* @param data DOM object
*/
 function getLablePosition(data) {
            var t = data.offsetTop;
            var l = data.offsetLeft;
            var h = data.offsetHeight;
            var w = data.offsetWidth;
            while (data = data.offsetParent) {
                t += data.offsetTop;
                l += data.offsetLeft;
            }
            var point = eval("({x:" + l + ",y:" + t + ",h:" + h + ",w:" + w + "})");
            return point;
}
/**
*Let the second component and the first component alignment
*/
function aligComponent(){
            //auto_msg is the second html component 
            var framePos = getLablePosition(data);
            auto_msg.style.top = framePos.h + framePos.y + "px";
            auto_msg.style.left = framePos.x+"px";
  }
```

Of course, if there are only two components, I can adjust the position of the second component.The big question is: in the JSF page, there are multiple such HTML component,if each one is to adjust the position, it will be very troublesome.
How do I can solve this problem?

Comment: JSF is in the context of this question just a HTML code generator, so your question is very confusing (as JSF has basically got completely nothing to do with it). A true [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help much in understanding and/or spotting the actual problem. My educated guess would be that you simply used a wrong doctype or a wrong JSF component for the very purpose.

Comment: Are you creating your own component?

Comment: I using the standard HTML component and CSS styles inside the jsf page,and I asked some people, they said the problem was caused by the JSF framework of CSS styles.